# Formula for find maximum column value of the minimum row values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula for find the maximum value of the minimum values of a row, take a look to the image for an example:

[image: example]

As you can see, now I'm doing the `min` of each row and than the `max` of the column of the *mins*, but my problem is that I need to do this to a table which is populated with an external data connection, and every time I refresh the data the number of rows changes, so I can't insert a *mins* column because I don't know how much rows I need (and, anyway, would be better not to insert another column)...So I need a formula for obtain this result using the table references.
I also need the avarage of the *mins*.

I'm not very skilled with array formulas, and I can't figure out how i can specify to the formula that it must first evaluate the row (a,b,c,d) for obtain the min, and then evaluate the array of the *mins* obtained for find the *max* (or the avarage).

Any help appreciated

Ettore

**Edit:**
I forgot to say that there are more columns in the table, and some of this must be skipped in the evaluation of the *min*, consider the image below:

[image: second example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following *UDF()*:

```
Public Function MiniMax(r As Range) As Variant
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim nLastRow As Long, nLastColumn As Long
    Dim nFirstRow As Long, nFirstColumn As Long
    Dim numrow As Long, numcol As Long, k As Long

    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
    nFirstRow = r.Row
    nFirstColumn = r.Column
    numrow = r.Rows.Count
    numcol = r.Columns.Count

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        k = 1
        ReDim ary(1 To numrow)
        For i = nFirstRow To nLastRow
            ary(k) = .Min(Range(Cells(i, nFirstColumn), Cells(i, nLastColumn)))
            k = k + 1
        Next i

        MiniMax = .Max(ary)
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

and if you desired automatic expansion or contraction of the range, this could be accommodated in several different ways.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thanks for the exaustive reply, onestly i did not considered to build an apposite function, i thought that with array formulas i could solve my problem, but also a custom function it's ok for me. Take a look to the edit for a clarification about my question, anyway using a custom function i think i could find the solution on my own with your input