# How do I write an Excel formula to find the earliest and latest times for multiple days in a column of timestamps

Tags: excel-formula

I have a third-party device that creates a .CSV file of results each time it performs a test, including the timestamp of when this test is performs. It can operate over several days. I've been asked to create an Excel spreadsheet which takes this .CSV file and extract the time of the first and last test of each day. This is to be used by an end-user who has no technical skills and the intent is for them to open this spreadsheet and print off a pre-formatted report.

So far, all I can do is find the earliest and latest timestamp, but not the earliest/latest times for each day in the range. I have no problem if there's only one day of data (this happens occasionally, but not always)

I can find the number of days in the range:

=COUNT(UNIQUE(INT(Results.csv!N:N)))-1

(because the CSV has headers, I have to subtract 1 since it's counted as unique)
Also, the number of rows in the column changes each time, and there's no way to estimate the number of tests performed each day.

I can find the earliest and latest timestamps like this:

=MIN(Results.csv!N:N)
=MAX(Results.csv!N:N)

What I can't figure out is to do the mininum/maximum time for each day.

I've tried several variations on

=if (MIN(INT(Results.csv!N:N)), MIN(TRUNC(Results.csv),"")
=if (MIN(INT(Results.csv!N:N)), MAX(TRUNC(Results.csv),"")

But nothing has given me what I'm looking for, if they even work

If the CSV file was in timestamp order, this would be easier, but the CSV file is sorted by other crieria and I can't change that.

I also can't use a pivot table since there can't be any user interaction (other than opening this spreadsheet - unless there's an automatic way to create a pivot table).

I have argued that we should write a program, but the powers-that-be are insisting on it being an Excel spreadsheet (something about it being easier to maintain - LOL!)

Any ideas would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Make a pivot table out of it, enable grouping on the date field, and display the `MIN()` in the data?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9iLpJNk-PTt9oeeUuRQ?e=NF4Shg)/below refers.

*Caveat: current state of following soln. requires Office 365 compatible version Excel:*

1. Prepare two sorted lists using the given date/timestamp field (here: col C: one ascending (`a0_`) and the other desc (`a0b_`); likewise do the same for unique days w/timestamp (removed this using `RoundDown`) - `a1_` and `a1b_` resp.
2. Min time: index `a0_` from (1), and match `a1_` to `a0_` w/timestamp, with 0 (exact match).  Because match with parm 0 identifies the first occurrence, this will be the `min` time for a given day, since the lists used in this step were sorted in the same order of direction.
3. `Max` time: use the other lists (here: descending), and adopt some method as (2) [now you'll find the first occurrence working from the largest date/time for a given day, i.e. the max).

---

Notes:

- This achieves the intended goal without helper functions*
- *note: whilst `let` will implicitly create 'soi-disant' helper functions, they are not the explicit flavour that requires a completely separate precedent/dependent columns...

---

Function:

```
=LET(
a0_,SORT(C4:C255),a0b_,SORT(C4:C255,,-1),
a1_,SORT(UNIQUE(ROUNDDOWN(a0_,0))),a1b_,SORT(UNIQUE(ROUNDDOWN(a0b_,0)),,-1),
c_,SORT(INDEX(a0_,MATCH(a1_,ROUNDDOWN(a0_,0),0))),cb_,SORT(INDEX(a0b_,MATCH(a1b_,ROUNDDOWN(a0b_,0),0)),,1),
z_,HSTACK(a1_,c_,cb_),z_)
```

[image: Function for min/max time per day]

---

Other notes:

**Not a straightforward task! upvoting q: since top 3 'similar questions' indicated by StackOverflow suggestions answer compeltely different questions, utilizing VB, powerquery, and are simply a distraction just the same as the single comment thus far on the poptic of using a pivot table. Hardly in keeping with the question let alone the tag name indicated for this Q!!*

For instance: StackOverflow 'suggested similar Qs' farce:

- [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983151/formula-for-find-maximum-column-value-of-the-minimum-row-values?rq=2) proposes a VB soln (I don't see you requesting such); in fact - you ask for something completely different (vide-licit 'Excel function' - per tag); there was only one solution to the question in hand, not to diferent from the present case....
- [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76917599/excel-table-with-a-dynamically-generated-column-header-for-each-month-between-gi?rq=2) deals with powerquery; and whilst a function is provided it simply brings back the entire range of dates, hardly the  same thing as finding the 'minima'/'maxima' across respective dates.

---

Comment: Thanks so much! It's going to take me a while to understand exactly what's going on (any answer is a learning experience for me)!  Several of us have been playing with this, and there was one solution that almost worked using the MINIFS/MAXIFS functions, but it wasn't working for the column of unique dates. 
I appreciate the time you put into this!

Comment: upvote/downvote (or approve answer) as you deem fit, for the benefit of future users.  I have linked the spreadsheet for read only with onedrive in my soln - you can save to local drive to edit I think.  

I can break it down for your briefly - but if you could give more guidance RE: which parts you don't get / need more detail that would help me hone my response.
Let - define variable, e.g. = let(dog, 1, cat, 2, dog) returns dog, i.e. 1, so its let (variable1, value1, var2, val2, etc... , then what you want it to return, in this case 'dog' which we defined as 1